# Keeping an object alive between calls to a single web page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, oauth, webforms

There are two web pages, let's call them foo.aspx and bar.com (bar.com is a separate website that the user authorizes access to their information on bar.com somewhere). foo.aspx creates an object that handles OAuth authentication, so it fetches the request token and then redirects to bar.com. Once authorization is complete bar.com redirects back to foo.aspx with authorization information. I want to take that information, put it in the object that I created during the first call to foo.aspx and then get the access token. However, when I get redirected back it just creates a new object, starting the authorization process over again.

Is there any way to keep that OAuth handler object alive between the calls to foo.aspx?

I tried using `Static` but that didn't seem to work and just creates the object over again.

Currently the code is set up as:

```
Static Dim handler As New Handler(...)

If Not handler.InformationObtained Then
    'Get request credentials...
ElseIf Not handler.OtherInformationObtained Then
    'Get access credentials...
End If
```

(I am using ASP.NET and VB.NET.)

If this doesn't make sense let me know and I'll try to explain it better.

If this has already been answered, I do apologize. I tried looking this information up but couldn't find anything. I tried things for persisting across a session, keeping an object alive between web page calls, and a few others and couldn't find anything or anything that seemed to be what I was looking for.

Thanks for any information.

EDIT:
As Jim said, it can be stored in the session or by the session (which ever wording is correct). However, what I am doing now is just storing the information in a cookie and then obtaining it on the second pass through and recreating the object. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is bar.com a separate website? Or would it be more appropriate to name it "bar.aspx" because it's on the same site?

Comment: Different website. It's the authorization site that the user get's directed to to authorize access to their information.

Comment: Check the documentation for oAuth. It will probably pass a cookie or querystring information back so that you can tell the user has been authorized. You'll have to check that.

Comment: I've read the documentation and I didn't see anything about a cookie being created because of all the exchanges. After the user is done on bar.com they return to foo.aspx and from there the access credentials are obtained by trading the now authorized request credentials.

Comment: Is this ASP.NET Web Forms or MVC?

Comment: I am using web forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't the Session suffice for storage of your object? Sorry I'm unclear on whether you expect the object to be available at bar.com, but I don't think so because you thought a static would do it.

Comment: I don't know...because I'm starting on my own foo.aspx page and then redirecting to bar.com. When the user is done on bar.com they return to user back to foo.aspx where the variable is recreated.

Comment: Sorry I don't see the problem, the Session will hold the object when it's created and then when the user returns you will check if the object is already in the Session, and if so use it instead of creating a new one.

Comment: Gotcha. Ya, I think a coworker said that was a way to do it, unfortunately though that is not advised here haha. (Just storing the information in a cookie for now, which hopefully works.) Thanks for your help though, I appreciate it.